# Understanding Haskell Parallel Fibonacci Results

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

Given:

```
module Main where

import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.Applicative

--main :: IO ()
--main = putStrLn . show $ spark [1..40]

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . show . runEval $ splitIt [1..40]

fib :: Int -> Int
fib x 
 | x <= 1    = 1
 | otherwise = fib (x-1) + fib (x-2)


spark :: [Int] -> [Int]
spark = parMap rpar  fib 

splitIt :: [Int] -> Eval [Int]
splitIt xs = let len = length xs
                 (as, bs) = splitAt (len `div` 2) xs
             in
              do
                xs <- fibPar as
                ys <- fibPar bs
                return $ xs ++ ys

fibPar :: [Int] -> Eval [Int]
fibPar []     = return []
fibPar (x:xs) = do
    a  <- rpar $ fib x
    as <- fibPar xs
    return $ a : as
```

I wrote two ways to calculate fibonacci for each element of `[1..40]`. Taking from [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch02.html#sec_par-eval-sudoku2), I ran fibonacci in parallel two ways:

(1) use `parMap` on the entire list. (first`main`)
 (2) cut list in half, splitting up each work with `rpar` (second `main`)

From reading the aforementioned text, I would've expected #1 to be faster:

> This illustrates an important principle when parallelizing code: Try to avoid partitioning the work into a small, fixed number of chunks.

I compiled and ran both (only including 1 `main`, commenting out the other) via:

- compile - `ghc -O2 Fib.hs -threaded -rtsopts -eventlog`
- run - `.\Fib.exe +RTS -N2 -s`

Here are the results for (1) and (2), respectively:

**(1) - use `parMap`**

```
 Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     1 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0001s    0.0001s

  Parallel GC work balance: 84.39% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N2)

  SPARKS: 80 (74 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 6 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    8.594s  (  4.331s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    8.594s  (  4.332s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    12,259 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity 100.0% of total user, 198.4% of total elapsed
```

**(2) - split list + use `rpar` on each half**

```
                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0000s    0.0000s
  Gen  1         2 colls,     1 par    0.000s   0.000s     0.0002s    0.0003s

  Parallel GC work balance: 12.41% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N2)

  SPARKS: 40 (10 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 30 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.001s elapsed)
  MUT     time    7.453s  (  3.751s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  Total   time    7.453s  (  3.752s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    14,398 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity 100.0% of total user, 198.6% of total elapsed
```

Why wasn't, as I understand the text to hint at, the `parMap` version faster than the split up + `rpar` version?

Answer (score 3):

First note that the work needed to compute `fib n` is exponential. That means that computing `map fib [1..n]` takes about the same amount of time as computing `fib (n+1)`. To see this just print out the time it takes to compute `fib n` for various values of `n`:

```
import System.TimeIt
import Control.Monad
...
main = forM_ [1..40] $ \n -> timeIt $ print (fib n)
```

To compute `map fib [1..40]` efficiently with two threads you want to equalize the amount of work done by each thread as much as possible. It turns out that one such division of labor which works pretty well is to have one thread compute `map fib [1..38]` and the other compute `[fib 39, fib 40]`.

If you create a spark for each `fib i` computation, the division of labor between the two threads is completely non-deterministic. To equalize the work done by each thread you actually want to carefully craft what the sparks are.

Now look at the number of sparks created in your two programs - 80 for one and 40 for the other. So clearly each `fib i` is getting sparked which means that in both cases the `fib i` computations are getting assigned randomly to the two threads.

Here is a way of getting a speedup of about 1.5 with two threads:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

fib :: Int -> Int
fib x 
 | x <= 1    = 1
 | otherwise = fib (x-1) + fib (x-2)

main = do
  let fs = (map fib [1..40]) `using` parListSplitAt 38 rdeepseq rdeepseq
  print fs
```

If you look at the RTS summary you'll see that it only creates two sparks - one for `map fib [1..38]` and the other for `map fib [39,40]`.

About the 80 sparks... if you use `parMap rseq` instead of `parMap rpar` the number of sparks created drops down to 40. So clearly `parMap rpar` is  creating a spark which just creates another spark which is completely redundant. In general I would stick to `rdeepseq` as an evaluation strategy - it's just simpler, easier to reason about and less error-prone.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, ErikR. For my own understanding, what would be a reasonable first argument to `parMap` in `parMap rpar  fib`?

Comment: In general I recommend always using `parMap rdeepseq ...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what follows is the only thing that is affecting the timing, but it definitely plays a big role.

*With a list, it is inefficient to split the work like this*

Remember that starting an execution in parallel takes very little work, so the fastest way to start executing something for each element in the list is just to run through them one after another and spark them with `rpar`. That's what `parMap` does.

In your case, `splitAt` is much more work: it needs to traverse half the list, then allocate space for another list. You might as well have sparked the `fib` execution during this traversal instead.

To see what I mean, try replacing `[1..40]` with `(replicate 1000 35)`. This is much more parallelizable: lots of reasonably difficult problems, all the same difficulty. With a 1000 element long list, `splitIt` runs in over 100 seconds while `spark` runs in under 1 second. **Your solution ends up spending the vast majority of its time splitting and appending the lists rather than computing anything.**